# TinyMCE replicates code automatically after insert content

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

After insert an image dynamically embedded in a `span` with `class="foo"`, every next line has the same span within the class.

```
// ...
const eg = '<span class="image"><img src="' + data.url + '"></span>';
ed.execCommand('insertHTML', false, eg); // or setContent or whatever I use
```

After that, if I press the enter key I'll get this again and again:

```
<p><span class="image"></span></p>
```

Question: Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rnv4q39f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could accomplish it with this workaround in the setup option:

```
ed.on('keydown', ev => {
    if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
        if (ed.dom.hasClass(ed.selection.getNode(), 'image')) {
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>&nbsp;</p>');
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
});
```

Which I extracted from this question question that asks the same (and I found today): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45394340/1684970. The difference is that using

```
ed.selection.setContent('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
```

the editor keeps the *non breaking space*, but using

```
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>&nbsp;</p>');
```

it doesn't.